# Center form in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center, navbar

What I'm trying to do is have the search box in the center of the navbar ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igjQH.png)). How would I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="brand" href="#">logo</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
          <div class="input-append">
            <input class="span4" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the default CSS that comes with Bootstrap.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this...

```
.nav-collapse{
    margin-right: 50%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KFYyd/2/)

Comment: I just tried that. It's ALMOST centered. It's a few too many pixels to the right (I'm guessing because of the logo)? [IMAGE HERE](http://i.imgur.com/1dtr3tI.png)

Comment: It didn't change anything at all this time :/

Comment: @Feriscool in the nav see the input and button center, under the space see the scroll...

Comment: Got it to work. For some reason, I had to set it at 0% for margin-right?

Comment: ...I don't think this is scalable without significant hacking.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't include Bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

wrap the form element within its own div and give it a class or an id, then create a custom line of code to center it, example:

HTML:

```
<div id="search">
*form code here*
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search { width: 200px; margin: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to override built in CSS in an application, use !important like so:

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto !important;"></div>
```

Or, put it in your css class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for a long time too, for Bootstrap 3. 
I finally found this solution which worked perfectly for me:
[Bootstrap NavBar with left, center and right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-and-right-aligned-items)
Just added a class to the  inside my navbar around my search box, with the css definition in Skelly's answer.

I did then have to apply text-align:left to some of elements in my form (e.g. typeahead suggestions attached to my search form).