# Bootstrap center navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to center my navbar with no luck at all.. Anyone here knows how to center it?

Here's my code:

```
            <nav class=" navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">HEM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">OM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VAD ÄR VI?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TJÄNSTER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VARFÖR?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
                </ul>
```

I cant find the rows in bootstrap.css, but if you really need the code from the css doc, i try to find it.

Comment: <nav> is a full width element? If it is, try using a fixed width on the <ul> and add to it a margin:0 auto;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works :- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WPpX4/1/)

```
<div class="text-center">
     <nav class=" navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">HEM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">OM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VAD ÄR VI?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TJÄNSTER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VARFÖR?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
                </ul>
       </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar .nav, .navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

Comment: Since my Fiddle was edited 17 times and even the accepted answer only was edited with my answer code, I dunno why my answer was not accepted... Cruel world :P

Comment: @Fiskolin I didn't even seen what u posted.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add css `.navbar-nav li {display:inline-block;}`  <-- this let all `<li>` tags lined up.

Check [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rrVga/1) to view more details.

Let me know if this was what you're looking for :)

Comment: Im so sorry, didnt see your post at all.. But now i did and it worked to :)

Comment: Np, just joking @Tommy :)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated 2017**

In **Bootstrap 3.x**, you can use the `nav-justified` class... No custom CSS required:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
     <ul class="nav nav-justified">
       <li><a href="#">HEM</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">OM</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">VAD ÄR VI?</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">TJÄNSTER</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">VARFÖR?</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.bootply.com/109568

**Bootstrap 4** there is the `nav-fill` class...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.bootply.com/bjgAw3F3Ps

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rrVga/17/)**

just a little fix to what @Fiskolin has done, if you want it to always be centered you should make sure that the UL will center all text by adding this to it.

```
ul { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this for **Bootstrap v3**.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar ul {
        float: unset !important;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
    }
}
```