# Responsive Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to make a Navbar for my site that has a dropdown menu on the left, image in the center, and collapsable item on the right. I am using bootstrap with less to style the navbar, but I am having trouble.

I have searched Stack overflow looking for ways to make this work, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-and-right-aligned-items) question, but the solutions there aren't working for me. I can't seem to get my image to line up so that its horizontal axis is centered with the dropdown menu, collapsable item, and navbar container. When I try the solutions like in the previously mentioned link, taking the image out of the flow of the page by maxing its position fixed, it always appears below the navigation bar. I can fix this for my screen by messing with the CSS attributes, but as soon as I resize the window things look awful.

Is there a way (possibly using less) to style the bootstrap navbar so that no matter what the size of the window is, I have an item on the left, image in center, and item on the right, all sharing a common horizontal center axis with the navbar?

**EDIT**

Okay, so I have changed my mind and decided to just add some links on the left, an image in the center still, and some links on the right. When the screen gets smaller, I want the links to collapse to the right offering a toggle button for a menu. The collapsing is working fine, but when the links are on the screen I want them to be horizontally centered in the nav bar, along with the image. The image right now is partially in the nav bar and partially out. I also want the image to slide to the left when the links collapse at smaller screen sizes. Here is my code right now:

Just a note that I am using django to serve the html, hence the syntax for the image src.

```css
#logo-with-slogan {
  max-width: 35%;
  padding: 3% 0 3% 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="logo-with-slogan" src="{% static " img/LogoWslogan.jpg " %}" />
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a href="#itemonelink">Item One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#itemtwolink">Item Two</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#signuplink">Signup</a></li>
      <li><a href="#loginlink">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you going to share any code you are using or are we to guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're looking to do something like this, with the image fitted:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>    
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-center" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" alt="Logo Here">
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#itemonelink">Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#itemtwolink">Item Two</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#signuplink">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#loginlink">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qo046pfk/)

Comment: This helped get the image centered, but the links are still right up on the very top line, not in the center.

Comment: Nevermind, that was because of a bootstrap variable I had mistakenly overridden. All is well now. Thank you!

Comment: When the screen size is small the image covers up the dropdown menu button on the right. Is there a way to make the image be left justified after the options collapse?

Comment: That's one small screen, but yes - you could add it to a media query to hide on the width you're looking for. EDIT: It doesn't appear to be a conflict until around 236px width on the fiddle

Comment: Excellent, thank you. My image is considerably larger than the one on the fiddle, and would likely cover the button on mobile devices. I'll throw in a media query to make sure that doesn't happen. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you're still there... I'm running into the issue with this code, that the brand element extends over the nav-toggle button after the collapse, so I cannot click the toggle button to bring up the menu, because it is covered up and does not receive the event

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar bootstrap</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Navigation bar is coolest component of bootstrap, you can easily create cool responsive navigation header for your website.

For information and detail please see this article.. 
[steps to create navbar in bootstrap](http://mytutorialbox.com/tutorial/bootstrap/advance-bootstrap-3/navigation-bar/1495366950625)

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#testNavBar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo / SiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="testNavBar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```