# Twitter bootstrap li align left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some long ordered lists and I need to left align them and wrap the text back under the text from the line above.  Right now the text is wrapping all the way back under the bullet.  I think I use a left pad to do this but for some reason it's not quite working correctly.

Below is my current attempt.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm just not searching on the right terms.

```
<li style="text-align:left;padding-left:5px; ">{{ item }}</li>
```

Comment: May be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-and-right-aligned-items

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/emw76bz4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution according to your fiddle

```
li{
padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
text-indent: -1em;
 }
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y7d3yogd/)

Comment: I thought `list-style-position` was for either `ol`s or `ul`s, not for their `li`s. That rule is unnecessary. Also, why `list-style-type: disc;` on an ordered list? The rest seems like a hack to me. Those `li`s should be inside an `ol` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding CSS rules, why don't you use an `ol` tag as a container? That solves it.