# Bootstrap 4 | Align <ul> to right

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to align a list to right on header, this is the code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-header-nav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link navbarMenuItem" href="#solution">Solution
        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link navbarMenuItem" href="#company">Company</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link navbarMenuItem" href="#openings">Openings</a>
    </li>
    <li style="display:none" id="getStartedHeader" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navbarMenuItem getStartedButtonHeader" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#getStartedModal">Get Started</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="app-login nav-link" href="undefined">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried with `float`, `ml-auto` and `justify-content-end`, but nothing, there's a new way to align everything on `div` to right like `text-right` on bootstrap 4?

this is what i need.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that BS 4 has flexbox, alignment is much easier. Here are examples for [left, right and center in the Bootstrap 4 Navbar.](https://www.codeply.com/go/qhaBrcWp3v)

*This answer was copied from: [Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items/20362024#20362024)*

Comment: dude, you're the real MVP :D