# html - Bootstrap navbar - How to align items left and right

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-4

i am making some new efforts with Bootstrap in Angular. I implemented a template navbar into my `html-site` from Bootstrap. The navbar contains some items in an orderd list and a search button and relating form. I want to align the text items on the left side and the search button and input form on the right side.

I tried things like : `nav navbar-nav navbar-left` from this question:
[[Bootstrap NavBar with left, center and right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-and-right-aligned-items][1]).
But this didn't helped.

Does anyone have an idea how to align the elements on right and left side?
Thank you so far.

The `html-code`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="text">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**SOLUTION:**

i solved the problem like this.
I extended the width of the of the navbar to 100 %. Before that the navbar width was limited so the left/right alignment of the elements  was not possible. 
The class `mr-auto` in the `<ul>`-tag just sets the margin left/right automatically.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-adjustment" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="text">
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-adjustment{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are using [bootstrap4](http://getbootstrap.com/), so you have to replace `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="text">` to `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="text">`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="text">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: exactly, the final solution was to add `mr-auto` and to set the width of the corresponding `div` to **100 %**
see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

use class navbar-right in the form class near search and navbar-left for other texts according to you

Comment: Can you provide the correct code next to your explanation? I think that would be an awesome help for OP.

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="text">

<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-right">

Comment: hi sadly this didnt work can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `style="float:right"` in div, you will get proper output

Comment: div which contains search box input field

Comment: <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="float:right">

Comment: this has no effect :/

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code instead of your html code. Hopefully it solved your problems. Make sure you have bootstrap 3.3.7 css, js and jquery include your code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>


      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form class="form-inline pull-right navbar-form">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you, this works almost perfect. But the single items are not next to each other. They are shown below each other. How do I get them in a horizontal line?

Comment: @Stelios See my example. Settings the LI's to a display: inline; will do the trick.

Comment: did you include the bootstrap css ,js and jquery properly ?

Comment: The question is tagged for Bootstrap 4, so the example should be for BS4.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this class to the UL in your navbar will "center" the links. May need some tweaking to get it right in the center, left or right.

See examples:

```
.nav-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
}

.nav-left{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
}

.nav-right{
  position: absolute;
  right: 1%;
}
```

```css
.nav-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
}

.nav-left{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
}

.nav-right{
  position: absolute;
  right: 1%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left nav-right" id="text">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```