# How to Fix bootstrap navigation toggle button in center

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a problem in bootstrap 4 navigation, I want to set left Logo/Brand and center Navigation button and right login/My Account button, I have tried to solve this, but when I click navigation button on mobile it suddenly goes to the right, Please look at codeplay http://codeply.com/go/8FOVzFRkfM

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" >
    <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand text-primary" href="#">
        <i class="fa d-inline fa-lg fa-stop-circle"></i>
        <b> BRAND</b>
      </a> <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar4">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar4">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item bg-white border-success"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a> </li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
      <span> <a class="btn navbar-btn ml-md-2 btn-light bg-info">My Account</a></span>
    </div>

  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use on `order-md-0 order-last` the `navbarcollapse` so that it is positioned *last* on mobile screen widths (when the Navbar is collapsed)...

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-md-0 order-last" id="navbar4">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item bg-white border-success"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a> </li>
    </ul> 
 </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/KkYoATqtFy

---

Related: [Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447)

Answer (score 0):

The `container` inside the `navbar` is a `flex` having `justify-content: space-between`, Hence `navbar-collpase` which is initially hidden gets displayed on toggle gets pushed below.

Solution: 
Making the `navbar-collpase` positioned absolute to the navbar will fix the problem.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar-collapse{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 56px; /*height of navbar in mobile*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir but I want when I decrease or increase window tab then toggle button automatic appear in the center and navigation link should be center like essayshar.com navigation, I have tried this code on codeplay website please check it my code https://www.codeply.com/go/8FOVzFRkfM

Comment: if you want the navigation links also to be centered, add this class too `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link { 
    text-align: center;
}`

Comment: Sir I want look like essayshark.com navigation same in bootstraps