# Move the Search Form to center

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm creating a webpage linkedin like with bootstrap-4. I am a beginner.
I'd like to move my form in the navbar to the center. How can I do it?
Here is my webpage:

```
    <body>
            <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" navbar>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Agora</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Messages<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Settings
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-xlg">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-5" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
            </nav>
 </html>
```

I removed some useless part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it before the navbar-nav and use `mx-auto`...

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Agora</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <form class="form-inline mx-auto my-2">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-1" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Messages<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Settings
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/XxoZUwh5C3

Related: [Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zim I solved my problem a bit. With the solution that she gaves me I moved also "messages". So I updated a bit my code :

```html
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" navbar>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Agora</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Messages<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 mx-auto">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-0">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Settings
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  
            </nav>
```

However the answer was really usefull! :)