# Bootstrap 4: Navbar Brand left, links center, other links right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've reviewed a couple of previous questions, namely: [Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items) but I haven't had any luck with solving my problem yet.

JSFiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/po0a6hf2/1/

Essentially what I'd like to do is have the branding in the navbar on the left, the main links in the center and finally the search and profile link on the right.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---Style Sheets-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!---Website Title-->
  <title>Padd</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!---Main Content-->
  <!---Navigation Bar-->
  <nav class="navbar nav-fill navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-none d-lg-block">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
          <div class="row">
          <!---Padd Branding-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images\notepad-logo2.png" alt="Notepad Logo"
                  style="width:150px;"></a></li>
          </ul>
          <!---Navigation Links-->
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarProductDropdown" role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Catalogue
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarProductDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Furniture</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lighting</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Decor</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Explore Pads</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Style Quiz</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!---Search Bar-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-end">
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 auto">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <!---User Profile-->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarAvatarDropdown" role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="images\man.png" class="avatar">
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarAvatarDropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarUserPic" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false">
                  <img src="images\man.png" class="avatar">
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#"><b>@Peter</b></a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Pads</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!---Bootstrap JavaScript and jQuery-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!---Firebase SDK-->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->
  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAY5wLj8AaQrhuIO2EOo4dSRkMJokUq3Yk",
      authDomain: "notepad-it.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://notepad-it.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "notepad-it",
      storageBucket: "notepad-it.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "975709176926",
      appId: "1:975709176926:web:c1aca8fc0c4f7db7"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.navbar { 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.main-logo{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px; 
}

.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 50px;
   }

.dropdown-menu > li > a { 
    height: 50px; 
}

.avatar {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow:
      inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 
      0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: transparent !important;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .avatar img {
    border-radius: inherit;
    margin-right:20px;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 998;
  }

  .newPaddButton {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow:
      inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 
      0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: transparent !important;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .newPaddButton img {
    border-radius: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 998;
  }

  .dropdown-menu {
    width:200px
  }

  #navbarUserPic{
    transform: translateX(68px);
  }

@media screen and (max-widht: 780px) 
{
    dropdown-menu {
        max-width:100%
  }
}

.navBarBrand {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen AND (min-width:991px) {
  .navBarBrand {
    padding: 6px 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not working

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist the nav is hidden for smaller screens, if you expand the white box to the left, you should see the navigation.

Comment: I used navbar-expand-sm, so, it will be hidden for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you to solve your problem.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white fixed-top">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Logo
      </a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample03">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
          <input class="form-control w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <div class="input-group-append">
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Tried this out and initially it achieves the desired effect, however, when the logo is added (width: 150px) it pushes the links and search form the the line below, rather than remaining in-line.

Comment: Please put your code in a jsfiddle which will show output. You previous jsfiddle is not working. After that I will try it again. Okay brother??

Comment: I've fixed the original JSFiddle with placeholder images now, it should be working as per the problem :)

Comment: You added all in a container. And in large screen all will be hidden. Now, what are you wanting actually?

Comment: On a desktop, I want the logo on the left, the links in the center and the search bar/avatar on the right of the screen. 

I'll create a separate menu for mobile