# Bootstrap 4 navbar with brand on left and links on left, right and center

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to create a navbar in Bootstrap where the Brand is on the left and the links are on the left, center and right. However, none of the [examples](https://www.codeply.com/go/qhaBrcWp3v) from the answered Bootstrap navbar alignment [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items) appear to do what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is an example of the navbar I am trying to create:

[image: like this]
[image: collapsed]

I have tried applying `mx-auto` to the center links but that does not center the links to the viewport correctly. Using `position: absolute` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` on the center links seem like a hacky solution and shouldn't be used if there is a flexbox solution available (especially if you are using an older version of Chrome where transforming text can make it blury).

This is my code currently (it is copied directly from example 3 of the previously linked examples). I want to add links to the left side after the brand while still being able to collapse everything in the navbar.

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto">Navbar 3</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
        <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I add links to the left side after the brand while keeping the other links in the example in the correct positions on the center and right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code , It'll work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex d-md-none mr-auto">Navbar 3</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-left">
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block">Navbar 3</a>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. The links that are supposed to be in the viewport center are offset by the brand. See: https://imgur.com/pACdrTJ