# Decreasing space in-between navbar elements Bootstrap-5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-5

This is what im aiming for (Ignore fancy background)
[image: What I'm aiming for]
This is what ive got:
[image: What I have]
How would I decrease the space between the elements,  and centre it in the navbar?
Heres my code so far - Using bootstrap 5

```html
    <nav class="navbar bg-primary mt-3">
        <div class="container-inline navbar-brand">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="ms-4" width="60" alt="Logo">
            <a class="text-light ms-5 fw-bold">TEST</a>
        </div>
            <a class="nav-link text-light">One</a>
            <a class="nav-link text-light">Two</a>
            <a class="nav-link text-light">Three</a>
            <a class="nav-link text-light">Four</a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What's `container-inline` for? Do you expect the navbar to collapse or stack vertically at smaller/mobile screen widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Bootstrap's Navbar, *only* use the [supported content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#supported-content). Follow the guidance from the docs...

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

> Navbars and their contents are fluid by default. Change the container to limit their horizontal width in different ways.

> Use our spacing and flex utility classes for controlling spacing and alignment within navbars.

So, following this guidance for your Navbar...

1. Assuming you want it to always remain horizontal, add the `navbar-expand` class.
2. The `nav-link`s should be contained inside a `navbar-nav` (supported content)
3. Use the spacing/flex utility classes. To center the `navbar-nav`, use `w-100` to create 3 equal width navbar divs/sections. Then `justify-content-center` on the `navbar-nav` to center content of the middle section.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-primary mt-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="w-100">
                <img src="//placehold.it/60x30" class="ms-4" width="60" alt="Logo">
                <a class="navbar-bran text-light ms-5 fw-bold">TEST</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                <a class="nav-link text-light">One</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-light">Two</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-light">Three</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-light">Four</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100">
            </div>
        </div>
   </nav>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/3XSDiDgjE1)

---

Since **Bootstrap 5** still uses flexbox like Bootstrap 4, [aligning Navbar content hasn't changed between the 2 versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items/20362024#20362024).